# USB charger of Macbook Pro disconnecting rapidly

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

Suddenly I am facing this strange problem, When I plug my type C charger on Macbook pro, it go on cycle of connecting and disconnecting. I have restarted multiple times, tried all the ports and different wall sockets and reset NVRAM is also done but no respite. Once battery is completely drains out and I put back on charge then it starts behaving normally. Afterward charger works fine for few hours and then issue reappears. I am stuck in remote place and don't have other charger to test out and can't visit to apple store due to covid issue. Any guidance will be helpful.
[image]

Comment: Are you able to measure the case temperature within 2 cm of the USB-C connection? Do you see charging slow when it’s hot and fast when it’s cool? Apple employees now take support calls remotely, so Apple Support is better than ever now for people not in a store physically IMO and in my experience.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem.   Try resetting the SMC.